# How to display data on the selected value?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to display data on the selected value? That is, on the left side there will be a list of values ​​and by clicking on one of these values, certain data for this value will appear next to , if  click on another value, the new data will be displayed, and the previous will disappear. At the moment, data is simply added side by side each time the value is pressed. Here's what it looks like.
[image]

So, how to fix (`this.filteredСosts.push(c)`) this so that the data is not just added next, but also changed if another value was chosen.

```
  reports: Reports[]
  income: Income[]
  costs: Costs[]
  selectedReport = null
  filteredIncome = []
  filteredСosts = []

  onSelectedReport(reportId) {
    this.selectedReport = this.reports.find(
      el => {
        return el.report_id === reportId
      }
    )
    if (this.incomeService) {
      this.incomeService.fetchAll().subscribe(
        income => {
          this.income = income
          this.filteredIncome = this.income.filter(
            (income) => income.income_id == this.selectedReport.r_income_id
          )
          if (this.costsService) {
            this.costsService.fetch().subscribe(
              costs => {
                this.costs = costs
                for(let i of this.filteredIncome){
                  for(let c of costs){
                    if(c.costs_id==i.i_costs_id){
                      this.filteredСosts.push(c)
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            )
          }
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m2">
    <mat-list>
      <h3 mat-subheader>Date</h3>
        <mat-nav-list>
          <mat-list-item *ngFor="let report of reports" class="center " (click)="onSelectedReport(report.report_id)">
            <a>{{report.report_date | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</a>
          <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        </mat-list-item>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m10">
    <div  *ngIf="selectedReport">
      <div *ngFor="let i of filteredIncome">
        <div *ngFor="let c of filteredСosts">
          {{c.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add your HTML code too ?

Comment: @programoholic Added by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply initialize `this.filteredСosts` when fetching.

```
      if (this.costsService) {
        this.costsService.fetch().subscribe(costs => {
          this.filteredСosts = []
          ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear

```
this.filteredСosts = [];
```